# Open a component in a new tab in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a component which I want to open in two places :

1. inside my application window (as a child component)
2. as a new browser tab \ window

I want to keep the component on the same application since it uses common `services`.

Is there an option to open it in a new browser tab \ window ?

maybe with a router?

If so, how can I pass parameters to it? (using `@Input()` or something else)?

Comment: mm i don't think you can open it in a new tab and be in the same app ..

Comment: A new tab/window would be a separate instance of the application, so you can't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe not even with a router?

Comment: not with any technique, either use popup